# Show software keyboard without EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

My goal is to show/hide on-screen software keyboard on some event and intercept input from that keyboard.

I found out that soft keyboard can be shown for some `View` class descendants, but I don't need any visual representation of the text edit widget on screen, just the ability to programmatically show/hide soft keyboard with input interception.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 23):

Even if this question was asked almost a year ago it didn't have an accepted and fully helpful answer and since I ran into the same problem myself I though I'd share my solution:

As Vikram pointed out this is the way to show the soft input:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.showSoftInput(myView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

*BUT* you must also set your view as focusable and focusable in touch mode:

```
myView.setFocusable(true);
myView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

or in your view XML:

```
android:focusable = "true"
android:focusableInTouchMode = "true"
```

Comment: How do you intercept the keyboard input?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. Intercept in which way? You can override View.onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event). Is that what you mean?

Comment: thanks! but i needed `myView.requestFocus()` right before `showSoftInput(...)` to get it working for me.

Comment: `setFocusableInTouchMode()` is what I was missing! This call alone is enough (also makes sure the view is focusable). It does not work for me, though, when set in XML, for some reason :(

Answer (score 5):

You can force the Softkeyboard to be shown by using:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.showSoftInput(myView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

and to hide:

```
((InputMethodManager) YourActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW).getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: This method didn't work. showSoftInput returns false and no keyboard is shown

Comment: it should work, but you can try the following line :
im.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can `always` show a soft keyboard input from manifest. add this line to each activity you want to show soft keyboard:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

Soft keyboard will show up no matter if there's no edittext in the view.
example:

```
<activity android:name=".ChatActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">

</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

> **But what about getting the input typed by user?**

You can use `EditText` as your `view` parameter, but you don't have to show that to user, instead, create a parent view (such as `LinearLayout`) for your `editText` view 
and `setVisibility` as `gone` of the parent view. 
Further, you can keep on getting the input by using the `EditText.addTextChangedListener`

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:focusable = "true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode = "true"
    android:id="@+id/edt"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to combine multiple previous answers for this to work

In the activity file, I added this piece of code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Assuming that I want the keyboard to pop up on click of a button, I added this piece of code in the activity (kotlin) file:

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
        binding.edt.requestFocus()
        val im: InputMethodManager =
            (this@MainActivity).getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        im.showSoftInput(binding.edt, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED)
    }
```

The code worked only after I added the line: ***binding.edt.requestFocus()***