# Android - How to show a custom keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-input-method

I have added a custom Keyboard to my application. **It works correctly when using another application that has text inputs**. I have changed the `settings / language and input` so that it is enabled and also used as default.

My problem is that I don't know how to show it in my application. I have a view where I draw a terminal screen using a canvas. There is no text input, but yet I do need the keyboard to show up.

How can I force the keyboard to show up ? I saw several ways to do it, using the manifest, using the input method manager, etc... but none worked in my case.
Must I focus an input for the keyboard to show up ? Can't I just show it and hide it whenever I want ?

Thank you.

EDIT : Imanaged to show the keyboard by adding a text input and clicking on it. But I still have no idea how to show it without a text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated it is already default. So, you can simply make it show up manually:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

To hide it:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

This way, user doesn't have to click on the text input to make key board show up. If this helped, please accept.

**EDIT**

You must also request focus:

```
yourEditText.requestFocus()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried this way as well as several other variants (toggleSoftInput, showSoftInput, etc). It doesn't work for several people it seems.

Comment: @Virus721 I think I have a solution for you. Try adding this: `yourEditText.requestFocus();`. It should probably work now!

Comment: Yes using request focus works, thank you. But I also need to add : `dummyTextView.setFocusable(true); dummyTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` as stated in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311563/show-software-keyboard-without-edittext Please add this to your answer.
Unfortunately I can't replace the text edit by my custom drawing view, or this code no longer works. I guess i will have to keep a hidden input somewhere. This is dirty and i'm surprised that android does not provide a way to do this easily and cleanly.

Comment: @Virus721 Yes, it is a bad way to do this!

Comment: Also this is not working if the edit text is not visible or if we're in landscape mode.

Comment: Not visible...? When do you make it not visible?

Comment: I don't want to show this edittext, so I change its visibility in the XML, but this causes this way of showing the keyboard not to work anymore.

Comment: Then why do you want to show keyboard in the first place?