# React Native Open Keyboard Without TextInput

Tags: keyboard, react-native

Is there any way to open device keyboard without using TextInput component in react native android ?

Is there a common way for both android and ios ?

For example onPress event of TouchableHighlight component.

I couldn't find in my searches.

Thank you..

Comment: Don't think there's a simple, react-native module for that. You may find this question helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311563/show-software-keyboard-without-edittext Looks like you will need to create native module to handle this.